# Routing table taking long time to update for adhoc networks and OLSR

Tags: networking, network-protocols, adhoc-network

I am using OLSR to implement adhoc network and analyse the throughput.I have olsr working on 3 interconnected computers on adhoc network. I am using jperf to simulate and visualise the data transferred.

Initially all the nodes are connected and data is transferred from A to B.Now in between of data transfer I block the mac of B on A.So, B will search and switch to another route through C.But this searching and switching is taking approximately 50-60 seconds whereas my understanding is that it should be done pretty soon(like within 10 sec.).I tried to change the olsr.conf file and reduced hello message time interval but no improvement in output. Can anyone help me where I am missing on this